# Does a Skald’s Raging Song qualify as a “similar ability” for the Pathfinder Chronicler’s Bardic Performance?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, prestige-class, bard, skald

In terms of both description and flavor, the Skald’s Raging Song appears to function as a Bardic Performance, albeit with different effects. It is treated as Bardic Performance for the purpose of feats like Lingering Performance, Discordant Voice and Extra Performance, as well as Bard masterpieces.
The Pathfinder Chronicler Prestige class has the Bardic Performance ability, as a Bard 2 levels lower, which is stated to Stack with “similar abilities”:

> At 3rd level, a Pathfinder chronicler gains this ability, which functions like the bard class feature of the same name, except that the chronicler’s effective bard level is 2 lower than her class level. Levels in this class stack with levels in any other class that grants a similar ability to determine her effective bard level.

So my general question is, would a Skald’s Raging Song stack with the Pathfinder Chronicler ability for this purpose? More specifically:

- Would the skald continue to progress with Raging Song, the same Way a bard would, or
- Would the skald gain the effects of normal Bardic Performances appropriate to their Pathfinder Chronicler level, or
- Would both be the case (this seems unlikely, but worth asking)?

Additionally, there are two additional questions, if the 2nd or third answer seems the case

- Are total rounds of Raging Song and Bardic Performance interchangeable (ie if I have 30 rounds per day of Raging Song and 15 of Bardic Performance, can I use Raging Song rounds for Bardic Performance and vice versa)?
- For abilities that exist for both Raging Song and Bardic Performance, such as Dirge of Doom, do levels in both classes stack for the Purposes of target number and Save DCs?

I think it’s also worth noting that I believe many of these questions would also apply to the question of a Skald or Bard multiclassing into the other, as well as to the question of how Skald interplays with the “Perfect Golden Lute,” Minor Artifact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes

[Raging Song](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/skald/#TOC-Raging-Song-Su-):

> A raging song counts as the bard’s bardic performance special ability for any effect that affects bardic performances.

The level stacking from chronicler is an effect of that ability that affects bardic performances (the level it's performed at). Therefore they would stack for that purpose.

Edit:

Note that the reverse isn't true:

> Levels in this class stack with levels in any other class that grants a similar ability to determine her effective bard level.

They only stack for determining their bard level, Skalds still use their Skald level for the purposes of their raging song.

---

Now for your other questions.

> Are total rounds of Raging Song and Bardic Performance interchangeable (ie if I have 30 rounds per day of Raging Song and 15 of Bardic Performance, can I use Raging Song rounds for Bardic Performance and vice versa)?

They are not interchangeable, they are two separate abilities with two different pools, just like how ki and panache cannot be used interchangeably. The only thing that mingles is their levels for the purpose of determining their effects.

> For abilities that exist for both Raging Song and Bardic Performance, such as Dirge of Doom, do levels in both classes stack for the Purposes of target number and Save DCs?

They use their effective level for determining their effects