# How do Multiclassed Bard/Class-With-Performances calculate their benefits from feats affecting Bardic Performance?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, multi-classing

Viewing [my question about how classes that grant bardic performances interact with Pathfinder Chronicler](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/206484/pathfinder-chronicler-and-all-these-bardic-performance-alike-archetypes-and-pres) may be useful pre-reading, because it lists a whole bunch of the classes that grant bardic performance analogues that I mention in the title, but this is not *about* PFC as such.

The question is, if you have multiple classes that grant rounds of bardic performance, and you take e.g. the Extra Performance feat, is that added to *each class's bardic performance pool,* or does it only get added once/create its own separate pool?